# Delete files only with logrotate

Tags: logrotate

I have an application which rotates its own log files on an hourly basis. Each hour I want to remove all of the files more then `n` days old. I have to use `logrotate` to do this because of business policy.

So what is the `logrotate` equivalent of running this command every hour?

```
find /var/log/app -name "*.old" -mtime +1 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: `-type f`  also to be sure to delete file and nothing else

Comment: did you have a look at `man logrotate` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a possibility and you need to test :

```
cat /etc/logrotate.d/customapp

/var/log/app/*.old {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 0
    notifempty
}
```

Why rotate 0 ?

> If count is 0, old versions are removed rather than rotated. (source : man)

Comment: no, this wont work.  logrotate will only remove files it created (rotated).  source: testing, since docu doesnt cover it.

Comment: `nocreate` option seems to make original log file to disapear. But anyway this will not work for files which are smaller than default size parameter (logrotate skips them). At least this is what I observe in my logrotate version 3.8.6.

Answer (score 4):

`logrotate` runs once daily and the script can be found here, `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` (on CentOS 7). If you want to run it each hour, you first need to move it to `/etc/cron.hourly/`. Then for the above command the equivalent `logrotate` script might look like this,

```
$ cat /etc/logrotate.d/app

/var/log/app/*.old {
  hourly
  rotate 0
  firstaction
    /usr/bin/find /var/log/app/ -name "*.old" -mtime +1 -delete
  endscript
  nocreate
  missingok
  notifempty
}
```

Comment: So basically you're saying that `logrotate` can't do what the OP wants, so, if they have a business policy that says they must use `logrotate`, then the solution is to *use* `logrotate` as a vehicle to run their `find` command every hour. OKAAAAAAY. I would warn the OP: this solution might be considered a policy violation.

Comment: If you don't put,

    firstaction  
      /usr/bin/find /var/log/app/ -name "*.old" -mtime +1 -delete  
    endscript  

`logrotate` will not remove the source log file.

Comment: Haha @Scott anyway the policy could not be followed then, because logrotate is incapable for things different then rotating and cleaning up files rotated by himself. The plus of this solution would be to find all this stuff in logrotate.d, but I personally would deny to follow the policy if this implies I have to reschedule logrotate to hourly for whole system. So possibly create a 2nd schedule for hourly logrotate with a dedicated config files including only hourly snippets..